# NHibernate Criteria question - how to search in table A, and add condition for B, not directly connected to A

Tags: nhibernate

Situation (following are entities):

```
public class OrderItem
{
...
      public Order Order
...
}

public class Order
{
...
      public Customer Customer
....
}

public class Customer
{
      public int Id
}
```

Question: how to create criteria, which gives me all OrderItems for some Customer id?

Comment: edited the question, hoping that other people with the same problem will find it easily ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ICriteria criteriacrit = session
  .CreateCriteria<OrderItem>())
  .CreateAlias("Order", "order")
  .CreateAlias("order.Customer","customer")
  .Add(Expression.Eq("customer.Id",id));
```

May not be exact for your model, but this should get you started. [Link](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).